# How to build vendor module without full aosp source code

Tags: build, android-source, vendor

Is it possible to build only vendor module without full aosp source code tree?

Say I have downloaded the full code base in my PC and able to build the same. Now I want to replicate the same in another PC. Since it has space constraints, I would like to build only vendor module by copying the same from the downloaded code base. Suppose if it has any dependencies, can we place them and build successfully?

How can I compile the particular module without downloading the full source code?

Answer (score 0):

if you have the aosp code, You can use this command to just build the vendor image. use this after you launched the target that you want.

```
make vendor
```

or

```
make vnod
```

Note: without aosp source tree you wont be able to generate the vendor separately.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But to build the vendor image as you mentioned, we need full aosp source code right? I am having only vendor module code, can I build the vendor image with this?

Comment: yes the AOSP source code is needed, because for building vendor image you need the make file instructions that is on device/vendor/model path, Soong build system scripts and files and also libhardware header files , the android default toolchains and utils. so beacuse of that you can not build vendor image outside of aosp source code.